# playframework, input disabled breaks play from passing the value?

Tags: html, forms, playframework

I have an input field that is filled in from a previous form(so the input is set to disabled on the second page) and we receive `null` for the value then. This works:

```
<input type="text" class="boxtpl" name="${field.name}" value="${user?.email}">
```

but this doesn't:

```
<input type="text" class="boxtpl" name="${field.name}" value="${user?.email}" disabled="disabled">
```

Is there a reason why this seems to break the framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disabled controls *shouldn't* actually be submitted with the form, so what you're seeing is in fact normal behaviour. According to the [HTML form specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12):

> When set, the disabled attribute has the following effects on an element:
>
> - Disabled controls do not receive focus.
> - Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation.
> - *Disabled controls cannot be successful.*

The definition of `successful` can be found [in the same document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls). It's a bit nonsensical to suggest that Play is broken because of this.

If you want to have a form field that user cannot edit while it should still be sent along when the form is submitted, you can use the [read-only](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) attribute, or use JavaScript to disallow user input.

**Update:** as pointed out in the comments, the following points may also offer a solution:

- It's possible that Play still keeps the disabled control's form values in the request object, and just doesn't bind them (so you could retrieve them from the request if needed)
- Use a hidden field to keep the form value in case you still want to submit the value, but do not want the user(s) to see the control

Comment: Another alternative is to have a second hidden field which contains the data. Also, you may find that play still has it in the params object request but doesn't bind it.

Comment: @grahamrb Oh it still keeps them in the request? Didn't know that, good call.

Comment: @tmbrggmn the hidden field option is the best alternative, more resilient

Comment: @PereVillega I agree, on the condition that the OP doesn't actually want to show this field. I suspect that he may still want to show the input field in the form, but rather not allow any changes to it.

Comment: @tmbrggmn then he can display it as a text label, neater than a disabled input :)